# WinForm Tab Control refreshing issue

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

This is my first question on stack overflow :)

I am a firmware/software developer (C/C++), and in the last few days I started working with C# to make a little application using Windows Form. So here is my question: I have a tab control with 3 pages, each one with about 15 controls (a grid, some button, labels, checkbox etc), and every time I switch from a page to another there is a refreshing (about 1~2 secs) which is very annoying. I tried to google this and found some solutions but no one seemed to work for me. Is there anything I can do to reduce this effect?

Thank you!

Comment: Might be arbitrary but WPF is a much better toolkit to build GUIs in C#. It's still supported in .NET unlike WinForms, and I have never had refreshing issues like you speak of.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @JackMiller Winforms may be old, but it is still in the current version of .Net. Why do you say it's unsupported? Edit: it **is** still supported - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms#cite_note-13

Comment: Adding some code might be helpful.

Comment: It is still supported, my mistake, but WPF has much better performance.
http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/about-wpf/wpf-vs-winforms/

Comment: Actually, I think it isn't matter of code, it happens whenever the page is painted.

Comment: Jack, I know but winforms appears to be easier to use and I didn't expect problems like this.

Comment: I believe that there are some time consuming events triggered. To find the source of this performance issue (20 controls per tab don't require one second to repaint) under debug, insert a breakpoint on all control events and identify what events are fired when you click on a different tab.

Comment: I agree with @Graffito.  Are you responding to `SelectedTabChanged` or something similar?  Are the controls data bound, causing a refresh of data that consumes cycles?  Something is happening as a result of the tab switch.

Comment: Graffito and @DonBoitnott, I will check this out. Anyway, I'm not controlling the SelectedTabChanged event and I'm not using data binding, I am at the very beginning so there is the interface, the form class and other 3 class which don't interact with the form class - for now.

Comment: I tried some other different solutions but without results; so I decided to port my application to WPF.